# Files ownership from second drive get reset on reboot

Tags: permissions, mount, systemd, lvm, system

every time I reboot my system (ubuntu server 22.04) the ownership of all my files and directories from my second drive gets transferred from my regular user to user _apt and group systemd-journal. How can I change this behavior?

Here's the relevant entry from /etc/fstab:

```
# /data was on /dev/data-vg/data-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-lrODXXtZW3GlkBTlrBaBvcQqeU4UZcMLUfgKwtjfkMrfq7TG3B1IdKMVQZyxE6Ql /data ext4 defaults 0 1
```

I can provide any other file contents or logs, as needed. I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: I think that the ext4 file system should not modify file ownership on reboot. Please run the command `ls -nl` "ell ess space minus enn ell" before and after reboot. `-n` shows the user ID number (instead of name), and it would be interesting to see if the user ID is also modified.

Comment: @sudodus Thank you for your reply. Yes, the user ID and group ID are changed from 1000:1000 to 100:101. I don't think the filesystem is changing anything but a process that runs at boot, however I have no idea which process could have this behavior.

Comment: You are probably right, and it is the same with me, I have no idea which process. But `user user_apt` and `group systemd-journal` makes me suspect apt and systemd. And for me the main suspected guy is systemd, but what process it starts, why and how to stop it is beyond my knowledge. I hope someone who knows will see your question and help you. Otherwise I would recommend that you write a bug report about it at [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). That is our method to communicate with the Ubuntu developers.